# In the sentence "You, too.", is the comma acceptable?

Tags: punctuation, commas, writing, sentence-ends

I tend to think it is, as "too" serves the role of a referential phrase, repeating the verb-phrase of a preceding sentence, and "you" acts simply as a subject pronoun.  But, I've heard an argument to the contrary.

Answer (score 4):

*[The Chicago Manual of Style, Commas](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Commas.html?page=7)* (fifth question on the page), says no, but it's a pretty soft no. If you felt stylistically compelled, it's not clearly wrong.